# Is blocking Autonomous Systems numbers in the firewall a good practice?

Tags: firewalls, blacklist, bgp

In response to low-hanging fruit attacks (accounts creation, image sending etc.) which request rates goes below our rate-limiting rules and are not blocked, we started blocking AS numbers from countries in which we do not operate. We started to do this because attackers changed their IP every 10 requests or so, so blocking the whole autonomous system was easier for us to mitigate the attack.

But I'm afraid that this "habit" can have unpredictable consequences. As AS numbers can change over time, we can for example end with real customers being blocked. But I can't think of more bad cases that can happen.

So, is blocking AS numbers something people usually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is been a common blunt instrument for at least 2 decades, in my experience. Some firewalls also maintain IP lists for blocks of country IPs so your rules can simply reference the dynamic list.

The mitigation for AS number changing is to simply review your firewall rules periodically to ensure that the rules are still fit-for-purpose, which is something you are supposed to do anyway.